# CSS flex-end behaviour has changed from Chrome 64 to 65

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, upgrade

I just noticed a weird bug when I upgraded from Chrome 64 to 65. The behaviour of a `flex` styled div suddenly changed.

I have a div styled like so:

```css
.modal-add-branch .modal-body .modal-pill-row .search-col {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-pill-row with-search row">
    <div class="col-xs-9"></h3></div>
    <div class="search-col col-xs-3">
        <span class="search pull-right input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" value="" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is *supposed* to look like this (and it *did*, before Chrome 65):

[image]

But after upgrading to Chrome 65, it suddenly overflows the modal container and looks like this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that upgrades aren't supposed to retroactively break features. Could someone on the Chrome team help me understand what's happening here?

Comment: It's hard to tell without being able to reproduce the problem. Have you tried [**`margin-left: auto`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) (or `-right`) on the flex item? Maybe that will pin it into place in both versions.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that upgrades aren't supposed to retroactively break features." Hahahahahahahaha that's Chrome for you. I've been tracking similar regressions (that's what they're called) on and off since **version 40** of Chrome. Just about every single major release of Chrome breaks a completely random feature for no rhyme or reason - it's like the Chrome team is doing that on purpose just to keep us on our toes. On the bright side, assuming this isn't down to a spec change, this'll probably go away by version 66.

Comment: @nikjohn did you forget to include some tags? You have a closing `h3` tag but no opening one.

Comment: Also, are you using Bootstrap? You have bootstrap classes but no link to the framework. Finally, your code isn't quite a *reproduction* of what you're showing; in Chrome 65 your demo still just has a search bar on the left and nothing else. Maybe adding bootstrap will help?